# how does wordpress collect the data on a post when saving

Tags: php, wordpress

So im now working on a custom meta_box_cb function on a custom taxonomy which has a search bar and a checklist. but when i try to add an tag via the checklist it doesnt save it when i save the post. the request body in wp-ajax is empty so im guessing it has something to do with how wordpress collects all the values.

So my question is: how does wordpress look for the things it wants to save?

if someone is wondering how my code looks:

```
    $defaults = array('taxonomy' => 'post_tag');
    if (!isset($box['args']) || !is_array($box['args'])) {
        $args = array();
    } else {
        $args = $box['args'];
    }
    $r = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);
    $tax_name = esc_attr($r['taxonomy']);
    $taxonomy = get_taxonomy($r['taxonomy']);
    $user_can_assign_terms = current_user_can($taxonomy->cap->assign_terms);
    $comma = _x(',', 'tag delimiter');
    $terms_to_edit = get_terms_to_edit($post->ID, $tax_name);
    if (!is_string($terms_to_edit)) {
        $terms_to_edit = '';
    }
    $args['selected_cats'] = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'gtag', array_merge($args, array('fields' => 'ids')));
    $gtagTerms = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => 'gtag',
        'hide_empty' => false
    ]);


?>
    <div class="tagsdiv categorydiv" id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>">
        <?php post_categories_meta_box($post, $box); ?>
        <div class="jaxtag">
            <div class="nojs-tags hide-if-js">
                <label for="tax-input-<?php echo $tax_name; ?>"><?php echo $taxonomy->labels->add_or_remove_items; ?></label>
                <p>
                    <textarea name="<?php echo "tax_input[$tax_name]"; ?>" rows="3" cols="20" class="the-tags" id="tax-input-<?php echo $tax_name; ?>" <?php disabled(!$user_can_assign_terms); ?> aria-describedby="new-tag-<?php echo $tax_name; ?>-desc"><?php echo str_replace(',', $comma . ' ', $terms_to_edit);
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ?></textarea>
                </p>
            </div>
            <?php if ($user_can_assign_terms) : ?>
                <div class="ajaxtag hide-if-no-js">
                    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="new-tag-<?php echo $tax_name; ?>"><?php echo $taxonomy->labels->add_new_item; ?></label>
                    <p><input data-wp-taxonomy="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>" type="text" id="new-tag-<?php echo $tax_name; ?>" name="newtag[<?php echo $tax_name; ?>]" class="newtag form-input-tip" size="16" autocomplete="off" aria-describedby="new-tag-<?php echo $tax_name; ?>-desc" value="" />
                        <input type="button" class="button tagadd" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Add'); ?>" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <p class="howto" id="new-tag-<?php echo $tax_name; ?>-desc"><?php echo $taxonomy->labels->separate_items_with_commas; ?></p>
            <?php elseif (empty($terms_to_edit)) : ?>
                <p><?php echo $taxonomy->labels->no_terms; ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>


        <ul class="tagchecklist" role="list"></ul>
        <div class='tabs-panel'>
            <ul class="categorychecklist">
                <?php
                wp_terms_checklist(
                    $post->ID,
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'     => $tax_name,
                        'popular_cats' => $popular_ids,
                    )
                );
            ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


    <?php if ($user_can_assign_terms) : ?>
        <!-- <p class="hide-if-no-js">
            <button type="button" class="button-link tagcloud-link" id="link-<?php echo $tax_name; ?>" aria-expandanded="false"><?php echo $taxonomy->labels->choose_from_most_used; ?></button>
        </p> -->
<?php endif;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Register global tag taxonomy
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
function create_tags_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                        => __('Tags', 'a'),
        'singular_name'               => __('Tag', 'a'),
        'search_items'                => __('Zoeken tags', 'a'),
        'popular_items'               => __('Populair  tags', 'a'),
        'all_items'                   => __('Alle tags', 'a'),
        'parent_item'                 => null,
        'parent_item_colon'           => null,
        'edit_item'                   => __('Bewerk tag', 'a'),

        'update_item'                 => __('Bijwerken tag', 'a'),
        'add_new_item'                => __('Toevoegen nieuwe tag', 'a'),
        'new_item_name'               => __('Nieuwe tag titel', 'a'),
        'separate_items_with_commas'  => __('Afzonderlijke tags met komma\'s ', 'a'),
        'add_or_remove_items'         => __('Toevoegen of verwijderen van tags', 'a'),
        'choose_from_most_used'       => __('kies van de meest gebruikte', 'a'),
        'menu_name'                   => __('Global Tags', 'a'),
    );
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'meta_box_cb'           => 'gtag_meta_box',
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array('slug' => 'tag', 'with_front' => false),
    );

    register_taxonomy('gtag', array('post', 'agenda', 'project', 'research', 'collaboration', 'expertise', 'tool', 'vacancy', 'person'), $args);
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'create_tags_taxonomy');
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont have the time to go deep in how it works. but it seems like everything on a page is a input element. but when you have 2 with the same name and value it get weird.

my issue was that i had one checkbox with was checked and one wich wasnt. i created a small script with syncs the 2 checkboxes

Comment: You shouldn't have two inputs with the same name in the first place.

Comment: @itachi i know but the client wanted something that required having 2 input's. the other alternative would have to been to link the search box and taxonomy list to 1 input. but that would require alot of custom work to be done